# DevExpress Filter Control: Add "All" or "Any" column

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, devexpress

I am using a DevExpress filter control for WPF

[image: The Filter Control]

Currently users can select eg. "Currency Equals GBP" .

I want them to be able to select either "All" or "Any" Beforehand, so that they can create a query like eg."Any Currency Equals GBP" or "All Currency Equals GBP" .

[image: Filter Control with All Any Selector]

Is this possible? Or is There any half decent hack Around This?

Comment: The way you show it - this is impossible. There is no such menu items as All or Any. But I am curious what result you want to achieve. Would you please add some data examples?

Comment: I'm using devexprees as a way for the user to specify a query, and then carrying out the query manually on a database to find a matching document. A document me have multiple currency fields, so I want them to be able to specify if all fields should match our just one.

Comment: At the moment I'm using the notor node with doesnotequal to express all

Comment: "A document me have multiple currency fields" - Do you mean that a document have fields like "Currency1", "Currency2", etc., and you want the "Currency equals AZN" expression to be either "WHERE Currency1 = 'AZN' AND Currency2 = 'AZN'" or "WHERE Currency1 = 'AZN' OR Currency2 = 'AZN'"?

Comment: @uranus. That's it exactly.